# Kali linux booting from usb get weird images and commands

Tags: linux, boot, usb, grub, kali-linux

Hi everyone after I added kali linux to usb and tried to booting it on th new pc  it didn't work it showed me some commands that are not clear to me I tried with secure boot but it's not about

it all works great on a laptop but it won't work on a desktop computer?

**here are the timeline pictures as I get them

[first one with a black background over the grub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2ICB.jpg)

[another with a famous logo but very slow loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP3gI.jpg)

[then these commands appear that are not clear to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDRSq.jpg)

[and finally this image of that black screen with a white line that just stands so infinitely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOfK1.jpg)

can it have anything to do with graphics? my is nvidia.
Thanks to everyone who can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I am working from Kali 2021.1 here in a VM.

First screen shot says your USB install does not have a correct driver.

Second shot says slow but also with a Graphics issue.

Third shot: I have not seen that here but the last line references Chipset which is a driver needed for Graphics.

Fourth screen says it cannot present a Login either GUI or text.

**Bottom line:** It cannot handle the Graphics in a USB setup. That is, not a full enough Kali Install to provide the nVidia drivers. That is what the issue is, I am pretty sure.

Try Kali in a proper VM on the desktop computer and it should work vastly better.